# Can SSH, but NOT SFTP - Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ftp, sftp, ubuntu-18.04

I have a new Ubuntu **18.04.3**. I can SSH fine, but I *can't* SFTP.

## SSH

[image]

## SFTP

[image]

This is my SSH configs

```
Port 8200                                                                                                                                              
PermitRootLogin yes                                                                                                                            
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no                                                                                                                                            
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*                                                                                                                                    
Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server 
MaxAuthTries 100
AllowUsers forge
```

I checked logs

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

I see this appended each time it failed

```
Jun 30 13:27:18 websocket sshd[3353]: Connection closed by 24.62.137.11 port 51216 [preauth]
```

## How do I make my SFTP to work ?

What should I check ?

Comment: What else is logged?

Comment: When I tried, I failed, only one line appended. What else should I checked or try ?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using passwords for sftp connections - then
"PasswordAuthentication no" should be replaced to "PasswordAuthentication yes"

- don't forget to restart sshd.